# How to get appointment object in Outlook VBA when displaying multiple calendars

Tags: vba, outlook

I wanted to write an Outlook macro to display the date and time of creation and last modification of an appointment. Working with some code I found elsewhere, I cobbled this together.

My Outlook 2013 calendar panel is configured to show two calendars: My personal calendar (using my Exchange account) and a shared group calendar (also an Exchange calendar). At first, I was happy with the result using appointments in one calendar, but I got an error when I selected an appointment from the other calendar and ran the macro.

The error was -2147221233: Method 'LastModificationTime' of object '_AppointmentItem' failed. Whichever is the *second calendar* raises the error.

```
Public Sub lsApptCreated()

    Dim CalFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim FocalItem As AppointmentItem

    ' Use the selected calendar folder
    Set CalFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

    If CalFolder.DefaultItemType <> olAppointmentItem Then
        Set CalFolder = Nothing
        MsgBox "This macro only works when the current folder is a calendar.", vbOKOnly, _
            "Check Creation Date"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count <> 1 Then
        Set CalFolder = Nothing
        If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "This macro requires an appointment be selected.", vbOKOnly, _
            "Convert Recurring Appointments"
        Else
            MsgBox "This macro requires a single appointment be selected.", vbOKOnly, _
            "Check Creation Date"
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set FocalItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

    On Error GoTo errhdl

    MsgBox FocalItem.Subject & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
            & "Date/time created:    " & FocalItem.CreationTime & vbCrLf _
            & "Date/time modified: " & FocalItem.LastModificationTime, _
            vbOKOnly, "Check Creation Date"

    Set FocalItem = Nothing
    Set CalFolder = Nothing

    Exit Sub

errhdl:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, _
            vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Check Creation Date"

    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Because I know very little about manipulating Outlook navigation panes, I thought about the more basic issue: Is there another way to get a handle on the appointment that might preserve all the properties? So I looked at some more code examples and decided to grab it by the EntryID. This worked:

```
Public Sub lsApptCreated()

    Dim Namespace As Namespace
    Dim CalFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim FocalItem As AppointmentItem
    Dim ApptItem As AppointmentItem

    ' Use the selected calendar folder
    Set CalFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

    If CalFolder.DefaultItemType <> olAppointmentItem Then
        Set CalFolder = Nothing
        MsgBox "This macro only works when the current folder is a calendar.", vbOKOnly, _
            "Check Creation Date"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count <> 1 Then
        Set CalFolder = Nothing
        If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "This macro requires an appointment be selected.", vbOKOnly, _
            "Convert Recurring Appointments"
        Else
            MsgBox "This macro requires a single appointment be selected.", vbOKOnly, _
            "Check Creation Date"
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'For some reason, when viewing multiple calendars, after you switch
    ' calendars it is not possible to access the LastModificationTime
    ' property using the item returned from the ActiveExplorer.Selection
    ' item. I discovered that instantiating the appointment using
    ' the EntryID gets around the problem.
    Set FocalItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    Set Namespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set ApptItem = Namespace.GetItemFromID(FocalItem.EntryID)

    On Error GoTo errhdl

    MsgBox ApptItem.Subject & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
            & "Date/time created:    " & ApptItem.CreationTime & vbCrLf _
            & "Date/time modified: " & ApptItem.LastModificationTime, _
            vbOKOnly, "Check Creation Date"

    Set ApptItem = Nothing
    Set Namespace = Nothing
    Set FocalItem = Nothing
    Set CalFolder = Nothing

    Exit Sub

errhdl:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, _
            vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Check Creation Date"

    Resume Next

End Sub
```

So my question is twofold:

1. Why does the LastModificationTime property not exist when my object
   is grabbed from the Selection?
2. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish what I want?

Thanks!